# In java 6 how to protect ArrayList from multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an ArrayList `l` for example.
And I have methods that can delete elements from the list.
And I also have method just reading from or iterating this list.

so I use synchronized keyword to protect this delete method. such as:

```
public void removeFromList(){

  synchronized(this){
     do list deletion.
    }
}
```

But I think this cannot prevent another method reading from list.
How can I make it safe to read this list?

BTW, i am only using java6, so java 7 synchronizedList cannot be used here. Sad.

Thanks.

Comment: Rather than writing your own, can you use [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)? Javadoc claims it's been around since Java 5 (1.5).

Comment: `Collections.synchronizedList()` was added in Java 1.2 according to the Javadoc. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)

Comment: Why do you think `Collections.synchronizedList` is a Java 7 feature? @Peter Lawrey: it even [exists in Java 2](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~michael/java/jdk1.2-docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) as it was added when the Collection API was introduced.

Comment: @Holger I got confused with singletonList which was added in 1.3. This was added before my time ;)

Comment: @JeffBowman, When the problem statement is, "I need synchronized access to a mutable list", then `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is almost always the wrong answer.  It's only the right answer if (a) the list is always small, or (b), and I'm quoting from the Javadoc here, "when traversal operations _vastly_ outnumber mutations."

Comment: @jameslarge We're talking about synchronized access to an ArrayList before Java 7, and I don't see why CopyOnWriteArrayList is a bad thing to link even if it has well-documented caveats and a specific use case. We certainly don't know enough about the problem (and frequency of operations) to make a solid engineering decision on the OP's behalf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

- Hide the reference to the list, so that only your class accesses it, and only in synchronized blocks.
- Use [Collections.synchronizedList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) to wrap your ArrayList in a synchronized version.
- Use [java.util.Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), a List that is already synchronized.